# Filter in R across multiple rows based on multiple conditions

Tags: r

In my dataset I have a check all question in which "no" is one the responses. I want to be able determine if any participants clicked "no" (child_tasks_2___0) and then another answer.

Here is some data:

```
child_tasks_2___0 child_tasks_2___1 child_tasks_2___2 child_tasks_2___3 child_tasks_2___4 
1                  0                 1                 0                    
0                 0                 
2                  1                 1                 0                 0                 0                 
3                  1                 0                 0                 0                 0                 
4                  1                 0                 0                 1                 1                 
5                  1                 0                 0                 0                 0
```

I tried this code:

```
results <- survey_all %>% 
  filter(child_tasks_2___0==1 &
         if_any (child_tasks_2___1:child_tasks_2___4)== 1)
```

However it only filters out child_tasks_2___0==1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `if_any(cols)` will return always TRUE if there is any value other than 0 in any of the columns in the row.  If we want to compare with a specific value, do the comparison inside each column by making use of a lambda expression (`~ .x == 1`).  In the OP's code, the `if_any` returns all TRUE and then when it compares with `1`, it is doing `TRUE == 1` which returns TRUE as `1` is coerced to TRUE

```
library(dplyr)
survey_all %>% 
   filter(child_tasks_2___0==1 & 
    if_any(child_tasks_2___1:child_tasks_2___4, ~ .x== 1))
```